# Is it possible in jade to unescape only html character codes?

Tags: javascript, node.js, escaping, pug, html-escape-characters

I have a database with text that has html character codes in it (`&amp;`, `&apos;`, etc.) and I'm displaying this text with jade markup (`p= text`). By default, jade escapes any html code, so `&amp;` becomes `&amp;amp;`. The text comes from external sources, so I can't just render it unescaped, but I want to find a way to escape everything *except* the character codes. Is there an easy way to do that in jade?

Comment: *"...has ascii codes in it (&amp;, &apos;, etc.)..."* Those are not "ASCII codes." Those are HTML named character entities. They have nothing to do with ASCII (other than that all of the letters in them just happen to fall in the ASCII range).

Comment: Okay, I'll edit the question, thanks

Comment: You could first unescape the whole content...

Comment: That isn't an option because I don't know what other kinds of code people might put in the text. I only want to unescape the character codes, because those are harmless and they are there in abundance.

Comment: @ChemicalRocketeer Not sure what you mean. What else besides character codes could be there? And what is the problem with unescaping them before escaping? List a real example

Comment: I get this text from several different external sources. If someone were to supply malicious text with script tags in it for example, that would be unescaped and the scripts would be running on my site.